# URL Rewrites Magento 2

Tags: magento2, overrides, url

I've encountered a weird issue with my Magento 2 URL Rewrites function.

It seems like my 3rd party plugin (Yotpo) is pulling an /admin with the ProductURL function.

So for example this is what is showing for the URL: https://www.aimn.com/admin/catalog/product/view/_store/2/id/1029/s/green-tribe-shorts-16010401-020/key/6657455bb042e8570e7aa9b5e7b7c20c4912c6ff0197ca486b8e4d2bf990e509/

And for a normal one: 
https://www.aimn.com/black-aim-high-singlet-16010717-010

Any idea why this could be? We are using a multistore and this issue seems to happen only for the Global store.

For example, on our SE it shows: 
https://www.aimn.com/se/catalog/product/view/_store/2/id/702/s/rio-logo-bra-16010317-019/

Any help would be appreciated.